# Getting Transmission remote web server to work outside my network

Tags: router, bittorrent, airport-extreme, transmission

I have a network that consists of a Netgear DG834 and an Apple Airport Extreme for wireless.

I have managed to set up transmission to work on my router, but I can't seem to get it going outside of that. I am assuming my set up with the Netgear is wrong.

In the Netgear I have added a TCP/UDP Service on port 9091 called Transmission.

I have then added firewall rules with this service, setting outbound and inbound to Always Allow, and attached the Airports local IP as the LAN Server IP, and the LAN User.

I am able to log into the Netgear using its external IP, but when I try to get through port 9091 (by appending :9091 after the external IP) I get a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Netgear is doing NAT and DHCP for your network, then make sure your AirPort is just in bridge mode; it sounds like you're currently doing double NAT, which causes hassles like this. Then give your Transmission box a static IP address on the Netgear's private subnet. Then point your port mapping from your Netgear's port mapping at the new private IP address of your Transmission box.